# how Jenkins pipeline multibranch plugin work with gerrit trigger plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I want to know if Jenkins pipeline multibranch plugin can work with gerrit trigger plugin.

Right now, it seems this plugin can only support the build with the commit has been merged into different branches.

Br, 
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Only `gerrit-trigger` plugin (as of 2.15.0) is currently compatible with Pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will check it.

Comment: There's a JIRA issue to make this feature work: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38046